# Can Gaara Survive Without Sleep?

Tags: naruto

So Gaara couldn't sleep, because Shukaku was inside of him, hence his dark circle eyes. There was that [guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Gardner_(record_holder)) who went crazy after trying to stay awake for 11 days for his science project. So how could Gaara function properly, let alone fight?

Evidence from Narutopedia

> During their first conversation when Gaara was a child, Shukaku warned Gaara that it would take control of his body and start killing people if he ever fell asleep

Comment: Please add reference to the guy you said went crazy after staying awake for 11 days. Where did you read that?

Comment: ay ay ayase sir

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is magic.

Comment: yeah, well, i was hoping we wouldnt have to come to that conclusion

Comment: Well.. Gaara is a ninja and his sleep deprivation made him psychotic.
He's also a jinchuuriki... He ain't human.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually pretty sure that gaara did sleep sometimes.

It's explained that when the host of shukaku falls asleep, shukaku slowly, key word slowly, eats away at that individuals personality and psyche. This is part of the reason that gaara is so unstable, because he DOES sleep sometimes, and when he does shukaku starts devouring his mind.

Comment: *It's explained that when....* If you want to add a reference, this is Chapter 135 pg. 9

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to justify Naruto's occurrences with human science. Naruto isn't science fiction, that's the greater point here.

Nevertheless, Gaara's black circles are a major plot hole in Naruto, because he had them since [birth](http://img07.deviantart.net/ee2e/i/2013/025/2/e/baby_gaara_by_pablolpark-d5so9es.png), and I'm pretty sure a premature baby didn't have the rational thinking required to deprive itself from sleep in other to preserve his identity from his inner demon. Also, he retain the black circles after losing shukaku, when he can sleep however much he wants.

Comment: *Naruto is**n't** science fiction* I think there's a typo there... or did I miss something?

Comment: Did not write "isn't"?

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpret the text "*Naruto isn't science fiction*" = "*Naruto is nonfiction, real-life*", but in my mind, "*Naruto (and almost all manga/anime) is a fiction, whether it's a sci-fi or not.*". I guess just a misunderstanding from my part.

Comment: Yeah, Naruto is definitely fiction, is just not part of the specific genre of science fiction, where things have to sort of make sense according to human understanding of science.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anakurak's answer, that Gaara does sleep but with a limited amount of time and wake up before Shukaku takes full control of his mind and body.

However, the dark circle is not a result of insomnia, but rather a birthmark he got since he had was a jinchuuriki even when he was still inside his mother's womb.

Reference:
[Why does Gaara still have dark circles around his eyes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/why-does-gaara-still-have-dark-circles-around-his-eyes/2147)