# Can the Tailed Beasts produce offsprings?

Tags: naruto

Is it possible for the Tailed Beasts to produce offspring of their own? Both 'male' and 'female' type Tailed Beasts exist.

The offspring would be hybrid, but still, would it be possible?

Comment: This question is speculative and might need improvement. Join us on chat so we can discuss about it --> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-

Comment: This is were the age old *asexual reproduction* joke pops up once more. `They can, asexually, it's like to clone themselves. Didn't 10 tails do that? He made 9 bijuus out of himself.`

Comment: Seriously ! If that's the case I have a question as well. Do tailed beasts eat Junk foods ? I am asking this because, I have seen they have teeth ;)

Comment: Yes, in anime anything is possible.

Answer (score 4):

There is no canon answer to your question. The tailed beasts as they currently exist in the Narutoverse are chakra creatures, not biological, and came into existence because one entity (the 10 Tails) had its chakra separated from its body (which became the Moon), which was then artificially split into a number of separate beings. There is no indication that any of these creatures (or chakra based entities in general) can reproduce themselves in any way similar to organic sexual reproduction.

If you're asking about the *kitsune* as a concept in actual Japanese folklore (which is the basis for Kishimoto's tailed beasts), then the answer is: the *kitsune* are considered a type of *yokai* or *kami*, who can if powerful and wise enough, take the form of a human being (usually but not limited to a beautiful woman). There are many stories of foxes in the guise of a beautiful woman falling in love with and marrying a human and producing offspring.

The real-life Sengoku general Takeda Shingon's wife Suwa Koi was believed to be a malevolent fox-spirit, and she bore him Takeda Katsuyori. Abe no Seimei in the Heian period was also considered a child of a fox.

Sources:

- Ashkenazy, Michael "Handbook of Japanese Mythology." 2003.
- Hearn, Lafcadio "Glimpses of Unfamiliar Japan." 2005.
- Turnbull, Stephen. "Nagashino 1575." 2000.

Comment: Related (to the second part of your answer): http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/748/how-are-the-bijuu-adapted-from-real-mythology